# Passing class method as selector problem

Tags: objective-c

I want to build a selector from a class method.

I'm doing it this way:

```
NavigationTreeActionHandler* handler=[NavigationTreeActionHandler self];
NavigationTreeNode* bombsNode=new NavigationTreeNode("Bombs","bigbomb.tif"
     ,handler,@selector(BigBombButtonPressed:));
```

I need to pass to NavigationTreeNode the target and the selector to the target method.
I try to get the target using the self property of the class object (Don't know if htis is the correct way to do it). Then I get the selector for the class method I want to call on the class.

Everything compiles ok but it fails when I use:

`[[handler class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector];`

I get a nil and don't really know why... could anybody help please?

Comment: `[NavigationTreeActionHandler class]` would be the preferred way to write `[NavigationTreeActionHandler self]`, but it shouldn't make a difference

Answer (score 3):

A few suggestions:

- `[NavigationTreeActionHandler self]` will work fine to get the class object, but I would declare `handler` as type `id` instead of `NavigationTreeActionHandler*`, because it's not a reference to an instance that type
- `[handler class]` is redundant; `handler` is already the class object.
- `instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:` is only going to return nil if `handler` does not implement the `selector`. Verify your spelling etc., and try throwing in an NSLog to verify what you're receiving:

  NSLog("handler = %@ sel = %@", handler, NSStringFromSelector(selector));

But I'm unclear on what you're trying to do with `instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:` in the first place. If you're just trying to call the class method, wouldn't `[handler performSelector:selector];` do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely you're using code that assumes that calling the method `class` will get an object's class, and thus uses `[[handler class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:selector]` to get the method signature for the selector on the object `handler`. While that works for normal objects, that does not work for class objects, because of the different meaning of the `class` method on class objects, since the class method `+class` overrides the instance method `-class`, and `+class` simply returns the object it's called on, instead of the class it's an instance of (a meta-class).

The solution is that you don't even need to get the class at all, as there is a method you can call on an instance to get its method signature:

```
[handler methodSignatureForSelector:selector]
```

This is a much shorter and simpler way of doing what was intended, and also works for class objects too.